# paypal not returning to application after payment

Tags: java, spring, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In my current java/spring project, I am using the paypal-java-sdk to try implement a payment system to my application. A long time ago, I managed to make this work with a old project I've lost, with a code similar to what I have now, but now, when I run the application and try make a payment using the paypal sdk, I am redirect to the payment method selection page, and, either if I confirm or cancel the payment, I go to my account page instead of return to the application.

I have this code:

in my controller, this method receives the call from the view:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/checkout", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String checkout(@RequestParam("usuario_id") Integer usuario_id, @RequestParam(value="payerId", required=false) String payerId, @RequestParam(value="guid", required=false) String guid) throws com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException {
    return "redirect:"+this.serv.checkout(usuario_id, payerId, guid);
  }
```

in my service class, this 2 methods handles the payment using paypal:

```
  public String checkout(Integer usuario_id, String payerId, String guid) throws com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException {
    Usuario usuario = this.dao.findBy("id", usuario_id);

    String clientId = paypalDao.get().getClientId();
    String clientSecret = paypalDao.get().getClientSecret();
    APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(clientId, clientSecret, "sandbox");

    String redirectURL = "";
    if(payerId != null) {
      if(guid != null) {
        Payment payment = new Payment();
        payment.setId(map.get(guid));
        PaymentExecution paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution();
        paymentExecution.setPayerId(payerId);
        payment.execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);

        //saves the order data in the database and redirect to the order page    
      }
    } else {
      Payment createdPayment = createPayment(usuario, apiContext);
      Iterator<Links> links = createdPayment.getLinks().iterator();
      while (links.hasNext()) {
        Links link = links.next();
        if (link.getRel().equalsIgnoreCase("approval_url"))
          redirectURL = link.getHref();
      }
      map.put(guid, createdPayment.getId());
    }
    return redirectURL;
  }

  public Payment createPayment(Usuario usuario, APIContext apiContext) throws com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException  {
    Amount amount = new Amount();
    amount.setCurrency("BRL");
    amount.setTotal(this.cart_total(usuario.getId()).toString());

    String desc = "Lista de produtos comprados\n";
    for(Produto produto : usuario.getCesta().getProdutos())
      desc = desc + "* " + produto.getNome() + "\n";

    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setAmount(amount);
    transaction.setDescription(desc);

    java.util.List<Transaction> transactions = new java.util.ArrayList<Transaction>();
    transactions.add(transaction);

    Payer payer = new Payer();
    payer.setPaymentMethod("paypal");

    Payment payment = new Payment();
    payment.setIntent("sale");
    payment.setPayer(payer);
    payment.setTransactions(transactions);

    RedirectUrls redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    redirectUrls.setCancelUrl(request.getContextPath() + "/cancel");
    redirectUrls.setReturnUrl(request.getContextPath() + "/checkout?usuario_id="+usuario.getId()+"?guid="+UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    payment.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls);

    return payment.create(apiContext);
  }
```

anyone can give me a hint of what I am missing here?

Comment: What is the current behavior?

Comment: @Jai I just update my question to  add this information that I had forgotten.